# ¿Cómo eliminar los array session variables de múltiples pasos de un wizard?

Tags: php, jquery, wizard

Tengo desarrollado un simple `Wizard`, el funcionamiento es como el uso de un `tabs`, que solamente oculta y muestra el `div` en el paso que se encuentra.

```
<div id="step1" class="step">
</div>
<div id="step2" class="step">
</div>
<div id="step3" class="step">
</div>
```

El contenido se muestra de acuerdo al paso mediante `var step = <?php echo $step ?>;` si en la variable de `javascript/jquery` tiene la siguiente información `var step = 3;` se va mostrar el contenido del id `step3` es decir lo siguiente:

```
<div id="step3" class="step">
</div>
```

Para guardar los pasos que se encuentra el usuario actualmente y así evitar el retroceso del avance del mismo, estoy usando sesiones de `PHP`, para mostrarle al usuario el paso donde quedo y no comenzar desde el inicio, para ello tengo tres archivos `PHP`:

**saveTemp.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $step =  isset($_GET['step']) ?  $_GET['step'] : 1;
    $_SESSION['datos_form'] = $_POST;

    include 'php/libs/validate.php';

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    $json =  array(
        'radio'     => $radio,
        'step'      => $step
    );

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

**wizard.php**

```
<?php
    //session_start();
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
        session_destroy();
        session_start();
    }

    include  'validate.php';

    $r =array(
        1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
        2 => 'PayPal',
        3 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
    );
?>
```

**validate.php**

```
<?php
    $datosForm = (isset($_SESSION['datos_form']) && is_array($_SESSION['datos_form'])) ? $_SESSION['datos_form'] :array();
    $sPaso = isset($datosForm['__step__']) ? $datosForm['__step__'] : 1;
    $step = isset($step) ? $step : $sPaso;
    $radio   = isset($datosForm['radio']) ? $datosForm['radio'] : 1;
    $_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'] = $step;
?>
```

Ya los pasos guardados los recupero de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var step = <?php echo $step ?>;
    var radio = <?php echo $radio ?>;
</script>
```

El problema que estoy presentando es al finalizar la compra, donde estoy intentando eliminar las sesiones de los pasos `$step` para reiniciarlos al paso 1, usando la función `unset`:

```
if($payment === 'Completed'){
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['datos_form']);
    unset($_SESSION['__step__']);
    unset($_SESSION['formid']);
    unset($_SESSION['sPaso']);
    unset($_SESSION['Pending']);
    unset($_SESSION['radio']);
    unset($_SESSION['p']);
    unset($_SESSION['step']);
    unset($step);
    unset($radio);
}
```

He realizado un `var_dump($_SESSION);` y un `print_r($GLOBALS);` obteniendo la siguiente información:

```
[_SESSION] => Array
    (
        [datos_form] => Array
            (
                [__step__] => 3
            )

        [4b228aaae2a6a7ce403bc4ecbc481de6] => ../libro.pdf
        [cart] => Array
            (
                [0] => 11
            )

        [qty] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
            )

        [formid] => 64da7c62c643f40684f573acffb144eba6bfaf63
        [id_user] => 1
    )

)
```

`var_dump`

```
array(6) { ["datos_form"]=> array(1) { ["__step__"]=> string(1) "3" }
```

Cuando paso al paso 1 se obtiene el siguiente cambio:

```
[datos_form] => Array
    (
        [__step__] => 1
    )
array(6) { ["datos_form"]=> array(1) { ["__step__"]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Cuando paso al paso 2 se obtiene el siguiente cambio:

```
[datos_form] => Array
    (
        [__step__] => 2
    )
array(6) { ["datos_form"]=> array(1) { ["__step__"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que estás diciendo en la parte del problema, parece que el código está incompleto, he visto la demo que tienes y no hay conexión entre procesar pago e ir al carrito de compras nuevamente

Comment: No se si lo estoy viendo mal pero cuando haces el proceso de pago o terminar de realizar la compra puedes dejar la variable de sesión en su estado inicial, algo como if($procesoOk){ $datosForm['radio'] = 1; ($datosForm['__step__'] = 1;}

Comment: @fredyfx Hola, No he agregado el carrito, pero el funcionamiento del Wizard es independiente al carro de la compra a excepción del método de pago que ese sí lo llama, pero ese está vinculado a la demostración, es igual como un tabs que va mostrando la información en cada opción del tabs, lo que necesito es poder destruir todos los pasos y el método de pago seleccionado cuando el usuario este en el último paso siempre en cuando el pago se haya efectuado correctamente pero eso lo controlo yo, ya eso es mediante un if else PHP

Comment: @zerocool Preferiría borrar la sesión de los pasos y el método seleccionado, pero ya he intentado destituir la sesión con las variables independientes, hasta globales pero no sé eliminan.

Comment: Coloca como has intentado borrar la variable de sesión

Comment: Tengo entendido que para destruir una sesión igual primero tienes que tener el session_start() primero, por eso es que te lo comento

Comment: @zerocool Ya lo agregué como intente eliminar las sesiones, si lo tengo incluído session_start() sin ello no funcionaría el carro de la compra e incluso el wizard.

Comment: podrias incluir el codigo de cuando ya finalizas la transaccion donde validas los datos y eso??? para darte un ejemplo mas completo!

Comment: Hola @Bryro He editado mi pregunta nuevamente, agregando más explicación, no he incluído el código PHP sobre lo que me indicas porque es muy extenso, por otra parte no participa en el funcionamiento del wizard.

Comment: @zerocool He editado nuevamente mi pregunta añadiendo información vinculada al problema, espero de esa forma sea más claro el problema que estoy presentando :)

Comment: Sería posible que coloques en un repo el código del ejemplo en el que se reproduzca el comportamiento? intente replicarlo en mi máquina pero me faltaron archivos, sobre todo acá: var step = <?php echo $step ?>; que si lo coloco tal cual lo tienes en la pregunta no encuentra las variable ya que obviamente primero tiene que pasar por un script que las cree pero no se bien cual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo que tienes mal es el flujo de tu aplicación, ya que como comenta Byro en la otra respuesta simplemente con hacer los unset o session_destroy en ese punto debería andar. Por ello te dejo cómo pude hacerlo funcionar en base a tus archivos y ciertas modificaciones.

Tomé como punto de inicio el script wizzard.php esto debido a que es el encargado de incluir el escript validate.php y como este ultimo es el que crea las variables $step y $radio para usarlas en el html me pareció conveniente (esto nada más para mis pruebas), quedando:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
       // session_destroy();
       // session_start();
    }

    include  'validate.php';

    $r =array(
        1 => 'Transferenasdascia Bancaria',
        2 => 'PayPal',
        3 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
    );

    include 'index.phtml';
?>
```

Acá es mencionar que dejo el session_start() al inicio ya que validate.php usa las sesiones así que desde acá inicio la sesión directamente e independientemente de lo que suceda. No se que indicas con isset($_GET['P']) obviamente deseas destruir la sesión cuando tienes el parametro P pero más de allí no veo el flujo en éste punto. Otro detalle es que el html lo llame index.phtml y desde el wizzard lo incluyo al final, simplemente para que abajo cuando indicas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step = <?php echo $step ?>;
        var radio = <?php echo $radio ?>;
</script>
```

Ya estén creadas con los valores iniciales esas variables $step y $radio.

Luego todo lo demás está igual, a diferencia de pay1.php que quedó así:

```
<?php
session_start();
$payment = 'Completed';
if($payment === 'Completed'){
    session_destroy();
}
?>
```

De nuevo en éste punto lo primero que hago es iniciar la sesión, que abajo la vaya a destruir, agregarle o quitarle datos es otra cosa, la inicio porque para destruir la sesión tiene que estar iniciada la misma como lo indican en la documentación:

[session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-destroy.php)

> session_destroy() destruye toda la información asociada con la sesión actual. No destruye ninguna de las variables globales asociadas con la sesión, ni destruye la cookie de sesión. Para volver a utilizar las variables de sesión se debe llamar a session_start().

Tomar en cuenta que dice "sesión actual" por ello tiene que estar iniciada la sesión para que sepa cuál va a destruir.

Además comentan que no se debe usar unset ya que ésto es para códigos php obsoletos:

> Usar sólo session_unset() para códigos antiguos obsoletos que no usan $_SESSION.

Ahora si te fijas el flujo es en primera instancia iniciar la sesión y crear las variables necesarias, luego la aplicación por cada paso inicia la sesión y modifica las variables de la misma guardando el paso en el que se encuentra y cuando va al ultimo paso se inicia la sesión y si el pago ha sido completado entonces destruye la sesión. En todos los script donde utilizamos la sesión lo primero que está es la inicialización de la misma.

Dejo en un repositorio el código con las instrucciones para ejecutarlo:

[wizzard y sessions github](https://github.com/zerocoolstack/sessionWizzard)

Actualicé el código en el github, quedando el archivo pay1.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$payment = 'Completed';
if($payment === 'Completed'){
    $_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['datos_form']['radio'] = 1;
}
?>

Así no se elimina toda la sesión
```

EDITO:
Luego de conversar vimos que efectivamente era un problema con el flujo de la aplicación, lo primero que hace index.php es incluir validate.php que tiene la creación de las variables $step y $radio (verificando si existen en la sesión previamente), luego si el paso era el número 3 se incluía el archivo success_paypal.php que modificaba la variable de sesión (o hacía el unset), seguido se creaban las variables de javascript step y radio con los valores de las variables $step y $radio creadas con anterioridad, por último se ejecutaba un función en javascript que tomando los datos de las anteriores variables envia una petición a saveTemp.php y ésta a su vez creaba las variables de sesión con las variables recibida. El tema está en el orden, si primero se ejecuta validate y crea las variables $data y $radio por más que se modifique la sesión con success_paypal.php ya esas variables fueron creadas por ende las variables de javascript quedan con el valor anterior o sea paso 3 y al enviar la peticion a saveTemp.php se creaban de nuevo las variables de sesion o se modificaban con ese paso 3.

Orden errado:

> +wizzard.php
>    ++validate.php (crear variable de sesion y variables $radio y $step)
>    +success_paypal.php (modificar la sesion)
>    +saveTemp.php (petición para almacenar el estado de la sesión con $radio y $stpe)

Orden correcto:

> +success_paypal.php (modificar la sesion)
>    +wizzard.php
>    ++validate.php (crear variable de sesion y variables $radio y $step)
>    +saveTemp.php (petición para almacenar el estado de la sesión con $radio y $stpe)

Saludos!

Comment: Si utilizo la opción `session_destroy` esto significa que se eliminara todas las sesiones, quizás ayude a solucionar el problema, pero esto significara que el usuario tenga que loguearse nuevamente en el sistema, estoy en lo correcto.

Comment: No te llega valores en las variables `$step` y `$radio` porque seguramente no estas agregando el archivo `wizard.php` en la pagina `index.php` o en la pagina donde se va ejecutar el wizard, por otra parte el código javascript debe estar en el mismo archivo, dicho código esta vinculado con ajax enviando información al archivo `saveTemp.php`

Comment: Se me ocurre ya que pierdes la sessión, cosa que no tenia en cuenta para el ejemplo ya que suponía que era un carrito sin cuenta de usuario, que puedes al momento de saber que ya esta el pago dejar las variables en su estado inicial, es decir colocar step en 1 y radio en 1. De igual manera inicializando la sesión al inicio y en el if acceder a la variable de sesión y editandola.

Comment: Es un sistema completo amigo, por eso trataba de usarlo mediante `unset` he intentado también lo siguiente `unset($_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__']);` pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Yo decía $_SESSION['datos_form']['__step__'] = 1 a ver

Comment: No amigo, no funciono tampoco, es imposible creer que no sea posible eliminar los datos, nada a la mente con los var_dump($_SESSION); y  print_r($GLOBALS); realizados, las sesiones de los pasos están en array, ninguna otra idea.

Comment: Edite la respuesta y el código en github, en el comentario me equivoqué ya  que tu variable se llama '_ _ step_ _' no 'step'.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95101/discussion-between-j-mick-and-zerocool).

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION` es una *superglobal* que no requiere el uso de la palabra reservada `global`. Si haces `unset()` a una variable global dentro de una función únicamente se eliminará el valor de la copia local al contexto de la función. 
Para hacer *unset* a una varible de sesión es más preciso:

```
unset($GLOBALS[_SESSION]['datos_form']);
```